# Download pdf file from server response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am creating a docx with php laravel, then converting to pdf and save it in my public server folder. Finally, I am sending a response to my client with the file.

Now, in client side, I am tryng to download it.

It's half working, because I can download a file (with exact same page number) but the file and all the page are blank page.

Here, server side sending my file to client side

```
    $docx->transformDocument($fileName . '.docx',  $fileName . '.pdf');

return response()->file(public_path($fileName . '.pdf'));
```

What I have tried client side

```
export const generateDocx = (offerData) => async () => {
  await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL2}offer/generate/docx`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json', 
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    },
    data: offerData,
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res); 
    // Create blob link to download
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', `FileName.pdf`);
 
    document.body.appendChild(link);
 
    link.click();
 
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
  });
};
```

what my console.log (res) contain :
[image]

I have also tried this :

```
    let fileName = 'aaa.pdf';
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
 
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(
        new Blob([res.data], {
          type: 'application/pdf',
          encoding: 'UTF-8',
          responseType: 'blob'
        }),
        fileName
      );
    } else {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([res.data], {
          type: 'application/pdf',
          encoding: 'UTF-8',
        })
      );
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.remove();
    }
    console.log(res.data);
  });
```

And with file-saver package

```
   var blob = new Blob([res.data], {
      type: 'application/pdf',
    });
    saveAs(blob, 'hello world.pdf');
  });
```

what my blob console.log contain :
[image]

Comment: I don't know, what `$docx->transformDocument()` does. But if you have a PDF document that can be opened by a PDF reader and has the correct amout of pages (even if they are blank) the chances are high, that the error is not on the client but on the server side. Do you have any other way to access the transformed document directly on the server, to check if it's correctly transformed?

Comment: Hello derpirscher, Well in fact I save my pdf file in server side first so when i open my pdf in server side public folder I am able to see the correct pdf with all my data.

Comment: Can you try using for example `curl` or Postman to execute that request and check if the file is downloaded correctly?

Comment: One thing I see, you are sending an `Accept: applicaton/json` header, yet the result you are expecting is `application/pdf`. A strict server might send an error, because, it wouldn't be able to satisfy the request. But I don't think, that's the issue here.

Comment: @MalwareMoon No, "getting" data with a post request is not unusual at all when that request has to send data to the server and that request is creating some sort of item in the backend which is then returned ...

Comment: I am actually trying with postman, I keep you in touch

Comment: Ok, so after some test my backend seems to work fine. I'm sending correctly my pdf file and it does exist. I continue my tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some test it's working

```
export const generateDocx = (offerData) => async () => {
  await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL2}offer/generate/docx`,
    responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/pdf',
    },
    data: offerData,
  }).then((res) => {
    var blob = new Blob([res.data], {
      type: 'application/pdf',
    });
    saveAs(blob, 'test.pdf');
  });
};
```

thank you all for your help